# Rails update_attributes creates duplicate record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have three models - Question, QuestionPaper and QuestionPaperQuestion.

```
Class QuestionPaper  
   has_many: questions  
end

Class QuestionPaperQuestion  
   belongs_to: question_paper   
   validates_uniqueness_of :question_id, scope: :question_paper_id 
end
```

In question_paper_controller,

```
def save_questions  
  question_ids_array = params[:question_ids]  
  @question_paper.update_attributes!(question_ids: question_ids_array.uniq)
end
```

The user can either add or remove questions from the Question Paper.
The params[:question_ids] will have all the ids of questions after adding or removing. I need to create a new record if a question_paper_question record for the question_id is not present. And destroy question_paper_question records which have question_id which are not present in the param.

I tried using update_attributes!. It does exactly what I want but unique validation fails sometimes.
What could be the reason for validation fail even though I have used uniq to get unique question ids?
Also any other elegant way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: You have added validation correct as it should be for double check you can add `indexes` on `QuestionPaperQuestion` table to avoid duplicates on db level.

Comment: Is it possible that some ids in `params[:question_ids]` already exist for `@question_paper`?

Comment: @AnthonyE Yes, there will be question_paper_question record for some ids in question_ids_array.

Comment: note: Do not rely on uniqueness validation in your model. Add a check on DB level.

Comment: @pascalbetz I have a validation in DB level as well.